# WP rest api - POST endpoint and store in the user meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create a custom endpoint on Wordpress to handle the WooCommerce authentication keys.

At high-level when you use rest api to generate authentication keys, those API keys will be sent back in a separate POST request.

So what happened is, my react website submit the authoziation request to WooCommerce/Wordpress headless server and the callback is the `wordpress_url/xxx/v1/authkeys`. It also needs to support https.

I am trying to add this `xxx/v1/authkeys` endpoint to wordpress and the purpose will be to extract the JSON data as below:

```
{
    "key_id": 1,
    "user_id": 123,
    "consumer_key": "ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "consumer_secret": "cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "key_permissions": "read_write"
}
```

and store the `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret` and `key_permissions` in the user meta-data related to the `user_id`.

My goal is to be able to get the keys when I am pulling the user information including those meta-data.

By default those fields are new, So I need to make sure that if `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret` and `key_permissions` do not exist in the DB, we create the fields.

For now, I have added in the `function.php`:

```
function handle_woocommerce_keys($request){
    $user_id = $request[user_id];
    $consumer_key=$request[consumer_key];
    $consumer_secret=$request[consumer_secret];
    $key_permissions=$request[key_permissions];

/* search user_id in db and store the keys as meta_data */


    $response = new WP_REST_Response();
    $response->set_status(200);

    return $response;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'village/v1', 'authkeys',array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'handle_woocommerce_keys'
    ));
});
```

As I am newby in php/wordpress, I have no clue how to add data in the user database for a specific user_id

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are missing is the DB store part then it's very easy with WP, you just need this:

```
// Load wp user object (if needed)
$user = new WP_User($user_id);
// or just save the data..
update_user_meta($user_id,'consumer_key',$consumer_key);
update_user_meta($user_id,'consumer_secret',$consumer_secret);
update_user_meta($user_id,'key_permissions',$key_permissions);
```

update_user_meta already does that check with missing -> create or existing -> update

Comment: thanks. How can I check that the value are stored properly ? I added this but I can't see the fields

Comment: @Seb all the data gets saved in the database in your wp_usermeta table, you can search in there using the user id and/or the meta_key field

Comment: thanks I found the issue. I was using Postman with the `content-type` set to `json`